# Structure to handle inter-device messaging

Tags: database

*How is the best way to handle messages through a server to multiple devices?*

**Scenario**

It will be an app capable of running on multiple mobile platforms including online in a web browser. A type of instant messenger. The messages will be directed through a server to another mobile device.

The back-end structure/concept must be basically the same as WhatsApp. Sending messages to one-another like that.

**What I think**

1. Have the device send it to the web-server.
2. Server saves it in a queue table in a database.
3. When receiver device checks for new message (every second) it finds it in the queue.
4. Remove it from queue and put message in history table.

**Final**

What would be a efficient way to structure/handle such an app to get similar results as WhatsApp?

Comment: "When receiver device checks for new message (every second) it finds it in the queue." what about pushing instead of pulling? Pulling every second will kill your server.

Comment: So you think the process is fine, except I must push it?

Comment: Yes, and if both ends (sender and receiver) are both connected when the sender sends the message, you can skip the database part altogether if you use push; and only use the db if the receiver isn't connected.

Comment: Cool, ok! Do you mind putting it as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to push messages instead of pull them every second. This has two big advantages:

1. Less bandwidth usage.
2. You can skip the database part if the sender and the receiver are both connected when the message is sent. Only queue the messages in the database if the receiver isn't connected.

So it's a huge performance boost if you use push.

If you have a web app using JavaScript you can use a JSON stream or, for new browsers, JavaScript WebSokets.

Comment: Noob question: i have checked JSON now, is that only a way to "compress" the data to be sent, but then one have to send it (connect) with Node.js for example?

Comment: @Nideo JSON is just a language which can be used to serialize data, much like XML but more compact and it works great for JavaScript.